# Golden Gate replication is extremely delayed

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle10g, amazon-aurora, oracle-golden-gate

We are using Golden Gate in production to replicate from Oracle Database into the Postgres. Together with that, the Golden Gate replicates also into another instance of Oracle Database.

1. Replicated Oracle Database is placed in the internal network of our company.
2. Target Oracle database is placed also in the internal network of our company.
3. Postgres is placed in AWS Amazon Cloud.

Replication Oracle->Oracle is without problem, there is no delay.

Replication Oracle->Postgres can have an inedibly large delay - sometimes in can grow up to 1 day delay. Also, there is no error reported.

We have been investigating the problem and we cannot find the cause: the network bandwidth is large enough for our transferred data, there is enough RAM memory and CPU is used only by 20%.

The only difference seems to be in the Ping in between internal network and AWS Amazon Cloud. In internal network the ping is approx 2ms and and into the amazon the ping is almost 20ms.

What can be the cause and how to resolve it?

Comment: You should contact Oracle support as GoldenGate is an Oracle product.

Comment: We have been thinking about calling the support but we had bad experience with it.

Answer (score 2):

You really should contact Oracle Support on this topic; however, Oracle GoldenGate 12.2 supports Postgres as a target (only).

As for your latency within your replication process.  It sounds like Oracle-to-Oracle is working fine and that is within your internal network.  The problem only appears when going Oracle-to-Postgres (AWS Cloud).

Do you have your lag monitoring configured?  LAGINFO (https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1221/gg-winux/GWURF/laginfo.htm#GWURF532) should be configured within your MGR processes.  This will provide some baseline lag information for determining how to proceed forward.

Are you compressing the trail files?
How much data are you sending?  DML stats?

This should get you started on the right path.